# Xcode NSTimer count++

Tags: xcode, swift, nstimer

I have a `NSTimer` running every 0.05 sec in a function called `moving`.
Inside `moving` I want a number to count up and show it into a label
and at the same time make an object move.

Now the problem is that it can only do one of those things at the same time. 
This is the code:

```
timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.05, target: self, selector: "moving", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)    

func moving() {

   countingUp = countingUp + 1

    label.text = "\(countingUp)"

    objectOne.center = CGPointMake(objectOne.center.x, objectOne.center.y + 1) 
}
```

Right now it's only counting up in the label while the object is not moving. 
However, if I delete the whole part of code of the label, the object is moving.
Can somebody please help me with this?

Comment: you might need to run code on main thread,

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let runloop = NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop()
let timer = NSTimer(timeInterval: 0.05, target: self, selector: "moving", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
runloop.addTimer(timer, forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes)
runloop.addTimer(timer, forMode:UITrackingRunLoopMode)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
    let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(0.05 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
 countingUp = countingUp + 1
 label.text = "\(countingUp)"
 objectOne.center = CGPointMake(objectOne.center.x, objectOne.center.y + 1)
}
```